# Check for value from another table before inserting into table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two mysql tables.  One of those tables(dwg) the user will be able to fill out and it will insert a row, but I need it to check the other table(form) and make sure one of the fields does not exist.

I have a query that says:

```
$projnum=$_REQUEST['project'];
$check = $con->query("SELECT Project FROM form WHERE Project ='$projnum'");
if($check->num_rows==0){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dwg (DWG, Date, Client, ProjNum, Project, Assigned, 
                             Location, Subdivision, STR)
    Values ('$dwg', '$date' , '$client' , '$projnum' , '$description' ,'$assigned' , 
            '$location' , '$sub' , '$str')";
}
else {
      return an echoed link
}
```

The problem is 'project' will have a dash(-)then 2 numbers after it.
If I fill out the form without the dash and last to numbers, it accepts it when it shouldn't, and if I add the dash and last 2 numbers it returns invalid.

Is there a way to check the whole number?  Getting rid of the dash is not a possibility.

Edit for clarity:
So on table: form, I have a 'project' called: 8008-17
When the person fills out the form I created to add a row to the table: dwg and they type in 8008, it should return the echo.
If they type in 8008-17 it should accept it and insert the row.
Right now it accepts the 8008 but not the 8008-17

If the $check returns 0 rows then it should insert the information, else it returns the echo.

Hope this helps explain the issue.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, but it seems like you have the condition backwards? You want to insert when there are matches, and not insert when there is no match? Then the condition should be `if($check->num_rows > 0) {`

Comment: Added more details to clarify the issue.

Comment: Well, that's the thing. You say the project is called 8008-17. If you type "8008", the query will get 0 results and it will let you `INSERT`. If you type "8008-17", the query will get 1 result and it will not let you `INSERT`.

Comment: Your right, I'm an idiot.  I got my thoughts turned around.  I did want it to return a value, if it does, then it goes on.  I had it backwards.  Thanks a ton for pointing me to my error

Comment: It happens to everyone! It always helps to follow the flow step by step when you run into stuff like this.